# Incomplete label in a tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-label

i am currently making an app which displays information about NBA players using an API called data.nba.net, i am trying to display information such as a player's last affiliation, height, jersey number, etc. But at some point in the process the labels cut off and it stops showing the rest of them.
I've tried messing around with the dimensions of both the window and the canvas, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. I am not an expert on tkinter, so i am not sure how do canvases and frames work, pls help :,).

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/batoo.png)

[What it looks like at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnaTH.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import position
from weakref import WeakSet
import nba_now
from nba_now import *
from tkinter import ttk

main_window = Tk()
main_window.geometry("420x420")
main_window.title("NBA NOW")

def players_windowP():
    n = 0.030
    win = Tk()
    win.title('Player Info')
    win.geometry("820x520")
    win.resizable(False, False)

    wrapper1= LabelFrame(win)

    mycanvas = Canvas(wrapper1, width=800, height=520)
    mycanvas.pack(side=LEFT)



    yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(wrapper1, orient="vertical", command= mycanvas.yview)
    yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="y")

    mycanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

    mycanvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: mycanvas.configure(scrollregion = mycanvas.bbox('all')))

    myframe = Frame(mycanvas)
    mycanvas.create_window((0,0), window=myframe, anchor="nw")

    wrapper1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=0, pady=0)

    stats = get_links()['leagueRosterPlayers']
    players = get(BASE_URL + stats).json()['league']['standard']


    for player in players:
        fname = player['firstName']
        lname = player['lastName']
        jersey = player['jersey']
        pos = player ['pos']
        height = player['heightFeet']
        team = player['lastAffiliation']

        data = Label(myframe, text=f"{fname} {lname} - {team}\n    Number: {jersey}\n    Height: {height} feet\n    Position: {pos}",
        font=('Arial', 25, 'bold'),
        relief = RIDGE,
        bd=6,
        padx=0,
        pady=30,
        borderwidth= 5,
        justify= LEFT)
        data.place(relx= 0, rely= n, anchor=N)
        
        n+= 0.45
        data.pack()

players = Button(main_window, text= "Player Info",
font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'),
justify=CENTER,
state=ACTIVE,
bd=1,
command=players_windowP)
players.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, anchor=S)

main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you add some screen shots of what is broke and how it should appear ?

Comment: Why don't you use `.pack()` instead of `.place()` on those labels in `myframe`?

Comment: I tried using .pack() but it piles them up at some point :(

Comment: I think that you have reached the maximum viewable height (it looks like it is around 32K pixels) of `Canvas`. Try using smaller font or multiple colulmns.